# Como obtener el nombre de un elemento[1], elemento[2] con jquery

Tags: php, html, jquery, select, selectores

tengo selectores que de nombre llevan:

```
<select name="selector[]" id="selector">
   <option value="1">Valor 1</option>
   <option value="2">Valor 2</option>
</select>

<select name="selector[]" id="selector">
   <option value="1">Valor 1</option>
   <option value="2">Valor 2</option>
</select>
```

Estos selectores pueden ser 1, 10 o 20 dependiendo de las circunstancias, y me gustaria saber cual selector es **al que dio clic** el usuario con Jquery, el selector[1], selector[2], etc.

Cuando es unicamente 1 selector, puedo realizar acciones sobre el con jquery facilmente asi:

```
$('#selector').on('change', function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     // acciones
});
```

Pero cuando el selector no es el primero esto ya no me funciona, por eso requiero saber a cual selector dio clic.

Saludos y Gracias!

Comment: ¿Como agregas cada selector?

Comment: El primer selector es agregado mediante html.
Los siguientes con Jquery usando append y clone.

Comment: Por norma general, **dos o más elementos nunca deberían tener el mismo id**. Deberías dar a cada selector un id diferente. Luego puedes hacer una función que mediante `this` te indique cuál fue seleccionado. Ahora te pongo un ejemplo.

Comment: Cuando envio mediante post, haciendo un foreach (php) puedo recibir todos los selectores sin problemas, que pueden ser indefinidos, pero si solo cambio el ID del elemento recibo 1 solo select.

Answer (score 1):

Por norma general, **dos o más elementos nunca deberían tener el mismo id**.

> Cuando se especifica en elementos HTML, **el valor del atributo id
>   debe ser único entre todos los ID en el árbol del elemento** y debe
>   contener al menos un carácter. El valor no debe contener ningún
>   espacio en blanco ASCII.
>
> <sub>▸ Fuente: [El atributo `id` en la especificación HTML](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-id-attribute)</sub>

En consecuencia, deberías dar a cada selector un id diferente.

Luego puedes hacer una función que escuche los cambios de los elementos `select` y mediante `this` te indique cuál fue seleccionado.

Puedes combinar `this` con cualquier propiedad del elemento para obtener el dato. Por ejemplo: `this.name, this.id, this.value...`.

```js
$('select').on('change', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  /*Valor de la opción seleccionada*/
  console.log("Valor: "+this.value);

  /*Nombre del selector seleccionado*/
  console.log("Nombre: "+this.name);

  /*Id del selector seleccionado*/
  console.log("Id: "+this.id);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="selector[]" id="selector1">
   <option value="1">Valor 1</option>
   <option value="2">Valor 2</option>
</select>
<hr />
<select name="selector[]" id="selector2">
   <option value="1">Valor 1</option>
   <option value="2">Valor 2</option>
   <option value="3">Valor 3</option>


</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar la función de la palabra clave `this` ya que 2 elementos no pueden contener el mismo ID, por lo que puedes hacer una la selección por el atributo `name` en este caso que me parece tus datos pasaran a un ciclo en php;

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $("[name='selector[]'").change( function(){
            console.log($(this).val());
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <select name="selector[]" id="selector">
   <option value="1">Valor 1</option>
   <option value="2">Valor 2</option>
</select>

<select name="selector[]" id="selector">
   <option value="1">Valor 1</option>
   <option value="2">Valor 2</option>
</select>
```

En general, el valor de this está determinado por cómo se llama a la función. No puede ser establecida por una asignación en tiempo de ejecución, y esto puede ser diferente cada vez que la función es llamada.

Documentación: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/this